# Why changing a line in my code will result in a stack overflow?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, union-find

This is a [union-find problem]: https://leetcode.com/problems/similar-string-groups/

If I change the line `parents[find(j)] = i;` into `parents[find(i)] = j;`, the code will result in a stack overflow. Apparently the path is too deep for the recursive find() method. But I can't tell what difference does this change make. Can anyone help?

```
class Solution {
    int[] parents;
    public int numSimilarGroups(String[] A) {
        parents = new int[A.length];
        for(int i = 0;i < parents.length;i++) {
            parents[i] = i;
        }
        for(int i = 0;i < A.length;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j < i;j++) {
                if(similar(A[i],A[j])) {
                    parents[find(j)] = i;
                }
            }
        }
        int ans = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i < parents.length;i++) {
            if(parents[i] == i)
                ans++;
        }
        return ans;
    }

    private int find(int curr) {
        int p = parents[curr];
        if(p != curr) {
            int pp = find(p);
            parents[curr] = pp;
        }
        return parents[curr];
    }

    private boolean similar(String a, String b) {
        int diff = 0;
        int i = 0;
        boolean consecutive = false;
        while(diff <= 2 && i < a.length()) {
            if(a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i))
                diff++;
            if(i > 0 && a.charAt(i) == a.charAt(i-1))
                consecutive = true;
            i++;
        }
        return diff == 2 || diff == 0 && consecutive;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Find()` is looking for the index matching the value, but you're changing the values in that array. You are most likely ending up with data like `parents[0] = 1; parents[1] = 0;` which will cause that recursive function to go into an infinite loop. Setting the opposite variables may cause the values to never have this occur, but it could easily happen if `numSimilarGroups` is given a different value for `A`.

Comment: @ItsPete You are correct. I add a output and the results shows the find() method stuck in a loop. Could you explain a little bit more why does this happens? I'm still confused now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `parents[find(i)] = j` allows a value to become smaller than its index by repeating the value that indexes can become. This can result in a situation where 2 elements have inversed indexes/values of each other. For example:

Given `A.length == 5`, your starting array would look like:

> parents[0] = 0; parents[1] = 1; parents[2] = 2; parents[3] = 3; parents[4] = 4;

The values we use will be for `similar` returning true. Starting with `i = 2, j = 1`, this would make the calls:

```
find(2);    //Array doesn't change in recursive function

//Resulting array after applying j to parents[2]:
//          parents[0] = 0; parents[1] = 1; parents[2] = 1; parents[3] = 3; parents[4] = 4;
```

Next, `i = 3, j = 1`:

```
find(3);    //Array doesn't change in recursive function

//Resulting array after applying j to parents[3]:
//          parents[0] = 0; parents[1] = 1; parents[2] = 1; parents[3] = 1; parents[4] = 4;
```

Then `i = 3, j = 2`:

```
find(3); find(1);    //Array doesn't change in recursive function

//Resulting array after applying j to parents[1]:
//          parents[0] = 0; parents[1] = 2; parents[2] = 1; parents[3] = 1; parents[4] = 4;
```

You can see now that we have our infinite loop set up (`parents[1] = 2; parents[2] = 1`). If `find` is called with 1 or 2, this will get stuck between these two values. We need two more steps to get there. `i = 4, j = 1`:

```
find(4);    //Array doesn't change in recursive function

//Resulting array after applying j to parents[1]:
//          parents[0] = 0; parents[1] = 2; parents[2] = 1; parents[3] = 1; parents[4] = 1;
```

Finally, `i = 4, j = 2`:

```
find(4); find(1); find(2); find(1); find(2); find(1); find(2); ...
```

---

Using `parents[find(j)] = i` means that the assigned value can't become lower because `i` always increments whereas `j` repeats for every iteration of `i`. `j` can be any value of `0 to i -1`.